# Sudo Alsactl Store Not Saving Capture Settings

Tags: audio, alsa, audio-playback

I am working on a project with alsa on the Raspberry Pi, and whenever I reboot my capture settings are reset. I have tried saving them via

```
sudo alsactl store
```

but this only saves the playback settings for some reason.

What do I need to do differently to save my capture settings?

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by adding:

```
amixer -c 0 sset Line,0 100%, 100% unmute cap
```

To my ~/.bash_profile

This is something of a workaround however, it would be better to figure out how to actually save the capture settings through alsa

Comment: Please accept your own answer with a click on the tick on its left side. Only this will finish the question and it will not pop up again year for year.